# How to get two-sequence representation of UTF-8 character using JavaMail's MimeUtility or Apache Commons and quoted-printable?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, quoted-printable, apache-commons-codec

I'm having a string which contains the German `ü` character. Its UTF value is `0xFC`, but its quoted-printable sequence should actually be `=C3=BC` instead of `=FC`. However, using JavaMail's MimeUtility like below, I can only get the single-sequence representation.

```
String s = "Für";
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
OutputStream encodedOut = MimeUtility.encode (baos, "quoted-printable");

encodedOut.write (s.getBytes (StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String encoded = baos.toString ();   // F=FCr
```

(Defining `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII` instead of `UTF_8` resulted in `F?r`, which is - obviously - not what I want.)

I have also already taken a look into Apache Commons' [`QuotedPrintableCodec`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html), which I used like this:

```
String s = "Für";
QuotedPrintableCodec qpc = new QuotedPrintableCodec ();
String encoded = qpc.encode (s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, this resulted in `F=EF=BF=BDr`, which is similar to the result Java's `URLEncoder` would produce (`%` instead of `=` as an escape character, `F%EF%BF%BDr`), and which is not understandable to me.

I'm getting the string from a JavaMail `MimeMessage` using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
message.writeTo (baos);
String s = baos.toString ();
```

On the initial store procedure, I receive a string containing a literal `�` (whose correct quoted-printable sequence seems to be `=EF=BF=BD`) instead of an umlaut-u. However, on any consecutive request Thunderbird makes (e.g. copying to `Sent`), I receive the correct `ü`. Is that something I can fix?

What I would like to receive is the two-sequence representation as required by IMAP and the respective mail clients. How would I go about that?

Comment: I get `F=C3=BCr`.  It shouldn’t be possible for getBytes(UTF_8) to produce a standalone FC byte.

Comment: @VGR Oh yes. That's right. However, I get some strange string when receiving from a `MimeMessage`, I updated my question.

Comment: `boas.toString()` is most likely your problem, as it uses the platform’s charset to decode the bytes.  I would use something like `String s = (String) message.getContent()`, which will take the message’s charset into account.

Comment: Well, sadly that doesn't help it, since the `MimeMessage` returns a string which literally contains `�` although the message's `Content-Type` header is set to `text/plain; charset=utf-8` which *should* work just right. (But the consecutive requests made by Thunderbird include the correct `ü`, no matter of how I retrieve the message's contents. However, I need it to work on the very first request...)